# Wrap collections in Value Objects

Tags: javers

I have the following entities:

```
public class ComplexEntity {
    public List<TenderLocation> tenderList;

    public ComplexEntity(List<TenderLocation> tenderList) {
        this.tenderList = tenderList;
    }
}


public class TenderLocation {
    public String location;

    public List<TenderAirline> tenderAirlines;

    public TenderLocation(String location, List<TenderAirline> tenderAirlines) {
        this.tenderAirlines = tenderAirlines;
        this.location = location;
    }
}


public class TenderAirline {
    public int ID;
    public String name;

    public TenderAirline(int ID, String name) {
            this.ID = ID;
            this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And the following test for comparing two `ComplexEntiey`:

```
public class ComplexObjectGraphComparisonExample {

    @Test
        public void shouldCompareTwoComplexObjects() {

            // given
            Javers javers = JaversBuilder.javers().build();

            // Construct test data
            // ComplexEntity:
            //  - List<TLocation>
            //  TLoation:
            //      - location: String
            //      - List<TAir>
            //      TAir:
            //          - int ID
            //          - String Name

            int locations = 3;
            List<TenderLocation> tenderLocationsBase = new ArrayList<TenderLocation>(locations);
            List<TenderLocation> tenderLocationsRef = new ArrayList<TenderLocation>(locations);
            for (int j = 0; j < locations; ++j) {
                int airlines = 10;
                List<TenderAirline> tenderAirlinesBase = new ArrayList<TenderAirline>(airlines);
                List<TenderAirline> tenderAirlinesRef = new ArrayList<TenderAirline>(airlines);

                for (int i = 0; i < airlines; ++i) {
                    tenderAirlinesBase.add(new TenderAirline(i, "Airline" + i));
                    tenderAirlinesRef.add(new TenderAirline(i, "Airline" + i));
                }

                tenderLocationsBase.add(new TenderLocation("BV" + j, tenderAirlinesBase));
                tenderLocationsRef.add(new TenderLocation("BV" + j, tenderAirlinesBase));
            }

            ComplexEntity baseEntity = new ComplexEntity(tenderLocationsBase);
            ComplexEntity referenceEntity = new ComplexEntity(tenderLocationsRef);

            // when
            Diff diff = javers.compare(baseEntity, referenceEntity);

            assertThat(diff.getChanges()).hasSize(0);

            // Change a single small thing
            referenceEntity.tenderList.get(1).location = "Difference_1";

            // then there is a single change detected
            diff = javers.compare(baseEntity, referenceEntity);
            assertThat(diff.getChanges()).hasSize(1);

            // there should be one change of type {@link ValueChange}
            ValueChange change = diff.getChangesByType(ValueChange.class).get(0);

            assertThat(change.getPropertyName()).isEqualTo("location");
            assertThat(change.getLeft()).isEqualTo("BV1");
            assertThat(change.getRight()).isEqualTo("Difference_1");

            // do another change
            referenceEntity.tenderList.get(1).tenderAirlines.get(1).name = "Difference_2";

            // second difference is not detected, failing the commented test
            diff = javers.compare(baseEntity, referenceEntity);
            assertThat(diff.getChanges()).hasSize(2);

            System.out.println(diff);
        }
}
```

At comparison my second change is not identified because the `compare` method is not comparing in depth my lists.

I have read here

http://www.atetric.com/atetric/javadoc/org.javers/javers-core/1.3.4/org/javers/core/Javers.html

that if I `"wrap collections in some Value Objects"` the deep comparing of the collection is possible.

My question is, How exactly I can wrap my collection into `Value Objects`?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the object something like below:

```
public class Wrapper
    {
      private final WrappedObject obj;

      public Wrapper (WrappedObject obj)
      {
      this.obj = obj;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong in you code is mapping, you didn't do it at all. You should map your entities as [Entities](https://javers.org/documentation/domain-configuration/#entity) using `@Id` annotation:

```
public class TenderLocation {
    @Id
    public String location;
    ...


public class TenderAirline {
    @Id
    public int ID;
    public String name;
    ...
```

Otherwise, JaVers maps your classes as `Value Objects` (objects without identity) which gives you limited diff experience.

Comment: I edited my initial question so you can see exactly which is my problem.